# How do I load an image while displaying loading screen react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to load the profile photo on my page before removing the loading screen, but can't figure out how. Right now I have an "if" statement in my render function that either returns the loading screen or the rest of the page.

I display the loading screen when I am fetching the URL for the profile photo and the name of user etc from firebase. But I can't figure out how to also display the same loading screen while the image is downloaded into my app from the URL because I download it in the JSX code.

Here is the code in my render statement:

```
render(){
    if (this.state.loading == true) {
        return (
            //returns jsx of a full page loading screen
        )
    }
    return (
        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 50, marginBottom: 50 }}>
            <Image style={{ width: 150, height: 150, borderRadius: 500 }} source={{ uri: this.state.userimage }} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

This code is simplified but this is basically what I am doing.

Right now the loading screen shows up when I am loading the URL from firebase etc, but then I set this.state.loading to false and the loading screen goes away, but the Image still takes a few seconds to load because it wasn't already loaded.

Could somebody tell me how to pre-load the image or some other easy way to load the image while my loading screen is still on then display it without delay?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) for my images and their [preload](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image#fastimagepreload-source--void) function.

Answer (score 0):

One method to do this is by fetching the image in the background, before the DOM is calling for it.

Below is some simple code that demonstrates this functionality.

```js
import React from 'react';

const IMAGE_URL = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";

const preloadImage = (url) => {
  return fetch(url);
}

export const App = (props) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // comment out this line and the image is not loaded until it is needed in the dom
    preloadImage(IMAGE_URL);

    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 3000);
    }, []
  );

  return (loading ? <span>Loading</span> : <img src={IMAGE_URL} />);
}
```